# How bad is it for SEO to use at 302 redirection instead of 301 redirection for HTTPS?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, https, 302-redirect

Recently my client has configured HTTPS. I recommended that he implement 301 redirection to 200. His developer could not do that and it is still using 302 redirects.

How bad it can affect a website if it uses 302 redirects?

Comment: A 302 will not do what is required. If you can serve a 302, then you can serve a 301.

Comment: @closetnoc I know but the problem where is occurring is not at web server, it is at load balancer. As they installed https on load balancer and www on web server. I hope you are getting what I am saying. I have suggested them to install either at load balancer or at web server but client is not listening or don't want to listen so I am asking would it harm my website as search perspective.

Comment: I assume you are trying to redirect http to https. If that is the case, then http must be handled for a proper redirect to occur. If you do not want http to be indexed and https to be, then you must use a 301 and not a 302. I have used load balancers before. These are often transparent proxy servers that look at session state and forwards the request packet modified to the the web server that is handling the session. Generally speaking, you can handle the certificate there too. Can it be a configuration issue with the load balancer? It should be smart enough to handle both protocols okay.

Comment: @closetnoc seems like you are talking sensible but I myself at my end I wouldn't be able to identify where they have the issue.

Comment: What load balancer are you using that supports only 302 redirection and not 301 redirection?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller that I have to confirm from my client. But I am sure 301 can be done and their developers are not able to do that.

Comment: @Rajat a temporary solution would be to set a rel=canonical pointing to the https version, whilst you guys solve the load balancer issue, keeping both sites live.

Answer (score 4):

Whilst I'd definitely always 301 http to https (as why would it ever be temporary?), Google have said that 301, 302, 30x [do not dilute your pagerank](http://searchengineland.com/google-no-pagerank-dilution-using-301-302-30x-redirects-anymore-254608) in SEO.

The team at [MOZ have recently studied this](https://moz.com/blog/arent-301s-302s-canonicals-all-basically-the-same-whiteboard-friday), and IIRC they're not so convinced.

If it was my site, I'd definitely tell/bribe whoever did your 302s, and get them to do 301s.

Answer (score 2):

It is not good to have those redirects as a 302.  Google's indexing will keep those old HTTP URLs, as the 302 redirect is a "Temp" redirect.  The HTTPS pages will still index, but may compete with the HTTP pages, that or the HTTPS may struggle to index.  Would be also concerned if there is a canonical link elements on the pages and if so, what version they point to... ie HTTP or HTTPS.

If the developer can't set the redirects to a 301, then you need a new developer.  It should be a simple adjustment.